# How to share azure storage credentials in my organisation to external organization securely

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-security, credential-manager

Currently Azure AD B2C is not allowed in my organization. we are using encrypted emails for credential exchange.. What are the diff ways we can securely share azure storage credentials across organization...

Comment: The requirements here could be pretty broad, have you looked at Key Vault as a possible option. You might have better luck asking this on Server Fault or Information Security Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Kane yes we can store in azure keyvault.. but external users cant access it unless we have B2C enabled in our active directory..

Comment: Do you mean B2B? (inviting guests to an AAD tenant is B2B)

Comment: @juunas Yes i mean i cant invite guests to my AAD as per my company policy

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @kane that you can use Azure KeyVault for storing Storage Credentials:

[image]

[image]

Then secret created , you can send this value and use as secrets.

[image]

You need Azure AD , you can invite an individual user(you need to give permisiions to access keyvault) and then they can access it. For doing that you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74904428/how-to-securely-give-external-application-access-to-key-vault-in-azure/74919196#74919196).
Alternatively, You can also send an encrypted file which contains the credentials.

Comment: We already use keyvault for internal credentials sharing.. but external customers who is outside my organisation  Azure Active directory can't be give access to this keyvault since i cant invite them through B2B..